# How can I invoke @after once for many scenarios?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, browser, cucumber

I have different tests scenarios written in cucumber/selenium using java, and usually I run tests from different features files using Tags like this 
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/step_definitions --tags @Tagname"

What I want to do is close browser instance after all my tagged tests are run.
How can I do that?
@AfterSuit is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the @After of cucumber to close your browser instances. Use the tag on a method in any of your step definition class. This will fire after every scenario is executed. 
If you are using a shared webdriver which runs all the scenarios in a single browser then this will not work as it will close the browser after every scenario.

In that case you will need to add a shutdown hook to your shared webdriver class which will shut it down when the JVM exists.

Comment: Mine is the second case, when all the tests are using single browser.  I tried the shutdown hook and it is working, it solved my problem. Thanks for the advice.